# adding two forms data in jquery and submitting

Tags: jquery, html

I have two HTML forms. When second form's submit button is pressed. First form should be added to second form data and then it should submit.

```
<form id="registration-form" class="clearfix" action="" method="post">
 <div class="form form-post-register">
   <div class="left-input">
     <label for="txt_name">
     <input id="txt_name" type="text" name="name" id="name"  class="txt fill-width txt-name" placeholder="Enter Name"/>
      </label>
     <label for="txt_email">
     <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="txt fill-width txt-email" placeholder="Enter Email" value=""/>
     </label>
     <label for="confirm_email">
     <input id="confirm_email" type="email" name="confirm_email" class="txt fill-width txt-email" placeholder="Confirm Email" value=""/>
     </label>
     <label for="password">
     <input id="pass" type="password" name="pass" class="txt fill-width txt-password" placeholder="Enter Password" value=""/>
     </label>
    <label for="confirm_password">
    <input id="confirm_pass" type="password" name="confirm_pass" class="txt fill-width txt-password" placeholder="Confirm Password" value=""/>
    </label>
    <label for="phone">
    <input id="phone" type="number" name="phone" class="txt fill-width txt-phone" placeholder="Enter Cell No." value=""/>
    </label>

     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**Second Form:**

```
<form id= "credit_card" class="form form-post-register" method="post">

  <label for="account_type">
  <h3>Select Account Type</h3>
  <input id="investor" type="radio" name="user" class="investor" value=""/>&nbsp;Investor
  <input id="startup" type="radio" name="user" class="startup" value=""/>&nbsp;Startup
  </label>
   <label for="txt_credit_card_no">
   <input id="txt_credit_card_no" type="number" name="txt_credit_card_no" class="txt fill-width txt_credit_card_no" placeholder="Enter Credit Card Number" value=""/>
    </label> 
    <label for="txt_cvn">
    <input id="txt_cvn" type="number" name="txt_cvn" class="txt fill-width txt_cvn" placeholder="Enter CVN" value=""/>
    </label>
    <label for="txt_address">
    <textarea id="txt_address" name = "txt_address" cols="30" rows="10" class="txt fill-width" placeholder="Your Address"></textarea>
     </label>
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
     <p class="rs ta-r clearfix">
     <span id="response"></span>
     <p>By clicking on Register, you agree to our terms of use and privacy policy</p>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-white btn-submit-comment" value="Register">
      </p>
     </div><!--end: .tab-pane -->
       </div>
   </form>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
jQuery('#credit_card').on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form1Data = $('#registration-form');
    var form2Data = $('#credit_card');
    var action = $("#registration-form").attr("action");
    var data = (form1Data.add(form2Data).serialize());
    jQuery.post(action, data, function () {
        alert('Form 1 and 2 submitted');
    });

});
```

I had found this jQuery code from `stackoverflow. The problem is that when i hit Register button. It does not alert`(Form1 and form2 submitted successfully);`I am unable to find the error. It receives`form2`data but i think it does not receive`form2` data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please do below changes:
1) add action to registration_form form (I have changed form id here - registration_form):

```
<form id="registration_form" class="clearfix" action="register.html"  method="post">
```

2) add action to credit_card form:

```
<form id= "credit_card" action="register.html" class="form form-post-register" method="post">
```

3) change submit button type to button:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-submit-comment" value="Register">
```

4) change script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#credit_card').on('click',function(e) {
    var dataString = $("#registration_form, #credit_card").serialize();
    var action = $("#registration_form").attr("action");
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: action,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Form 1 and 2 submitted');
        }
    });
  });
   });
```

I hope this will work:)

Comment: It is still not working. Please see this error. [http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=20jqywj&s=9#.VxoPfvl97IU]

Comment: I have removed that bit of code and i came to know that error had nothing to do with form submission. It still does not work. It is not even alerting `form 1 and 2 submitted`. And also there is no error. i have changed the method by `GET` and it gives data like this `register.html?user=&txt_credit_card_no=31265154751523486546511242547585858&txt_cvn=123&txt_address=ghfvghvgh`

Comment: the action of both the form tag are same or different?

Comment: Yes action is same. I have tried it like `action=""` on both forms and `action="register.html"`

Comment: New error occurred, `jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5 XMLHttpRequest cannot load `,  `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: I have run this script in my local system. its working properly.

Comment: I am also unable to understand the reason. I have tried it without ajax. it produces same error.